# How can I change stone_slabs to double_stone_slabs minecraft bedrock editon

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

I'm trying to replace stone_slab with double_stone_slab using the /fill command:

`/fill -83,4,-369 -79,3,-375 double_stone_slab 0 replace stone_slab`

However, every time I execute the command, it states:

> 0 blocks placed.

I've placed about 10 stone_slab in the target area.

How can I replace stone_slab with double_stone_slab?

NOTE: I want to replace the bottom slab. I do NOT want a slab on top. I would like it so that I can convert the normal slab on the left to the slabs on the right. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do know how to do it. Get a repeating command block, unconditional allways active and type in the command block ‘/testforblock X Y Z (coordinates) stone_slab’ then a chain command block, (make sure that the arrows on the top of the command blocks are both next to each other with the arrows both going the same way.) so a chain command block which is conditional always active that says ‘/setblock X Y Z double_stone_slab.’

Comment: Hi thanks for the help it worked thanks